# Multiple styles in HTML

Tags: html

Hi I have made a paragraph in HTML

```
<p style="font-size:50px" style="color:blue">this is my paragraph</p>
```

Why will this not show both the colour and the size. How could I fix this the colour is not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write in one style tag you using two tags so its not working.

```
<p style="font-size:50px;color:blue">this is my paragraph</p>
```

Using this please

Comment: color is not showing because css consider first  style class and don't read the other. Because multi attribute is not allowed in css

Comment: You mean HTML, not CSS.

Comment: You are using inline style.But put style tag more than one in one html tag which is not allowed;@SLaks

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not recognize duplicate attributes.
You can combine your styles in one attribute, separated by semicolons.

However, you should switch to actual CSS (with selectors) instead.